# How can I make dropdown menu when I click?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my script, but it work on mouse hover.

```
$(function () {    
  $('#nav li').hover(function () {
     clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
     $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
  }, function () {
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    }, this), 200));
  });
});
```

How can I make it dropdown in mouse click?

Comment: This is not a clear question at all

Comment: please share the target html

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jQuery`, but I guess you may try changing `.hover` to `.click`. BTW, I think this question is not really unclear, not event wanting to say it may be simple for those who know jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav li').click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('open');
        $(this).siblings('.open').removeClass('open').find('ul').stop(true).slideUp(200);
        $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle(200);
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest('#nav').length) {
            $('#nav li.open').removeClass('open').find('ul').stop(true).slideUp(200);
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jnCL9/)

Answer (score 1):

Replace .hover() with .click()

these are shortcuts for

```
   .on("hover",function(){})
```

and

```
 .on("click",function(){});
```